# How to host a web server in React Native app which can respond to GET/POST requests?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, server, webserver

I am building an app where I need to host a web server in my React Native app which can respond to `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` requests.

Use Case:
I need to send some data from my PC to my mobile app(where the server should be hosted) and then I will print that data from my mobile app.

I tried these packages, [React Native http-bridge](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-http-bridge) and [react-native-http-server](https://github.com/Strainy/react-native-http-server), but both are giving me errors which I don't know how to resolve.

If anyone has tried any of these packages or any other way to setup a web server in a React-native application, then please help :)

Comment: Have look https://codeburst.io/integrating-react-native-apps-with-back-end-code-using-fetch-api-8aeb83dfb428

Comment: Hey @VijaySinghChouhan, thanks for your reference but I don't want to setup a backend server somewhere and use it with app, actually what I want to do is just the reverse of it, which is, I want to setup the server inside React Native app, so when the ```componentWillMount()```, my server should start serving, and when ```componentWillUnmount()```, my server should stop serving. That's what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Use [React native http-bridge](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-http-bridge) package and follow their documentation, mainly the linking part of docs. And they actually forgot to add the "SERVICENAME" argument in this line:

```
httpBridge.start(5561, function(request) {
```

So, add the argument like this:

```
httpBridge.start(5561,"SERVICENAME", function(request) {
```

After this, the server will work fine in your native app.

Comment: Still not working!! I'm using the simulator (iOS), and I have disabled the Firewall... When I do a curl http://<deviceIPAddress>:5561 the App crashes or does not respond!! Any ideas?!

Comment: Unfortunately, react-native-http-bridge is not maintained and is not compatible with newer versions.

Comment: Checkout my answer, I created a maintained version of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a repo called [react-native-http-bridge-refurbished](https://github.com/Alwinator/react-native-http-bridge-refurbished).

It is a maintained fork of react-native-http-bridge with both old and cool new features.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const server = new BridgeServer('http_service', true);
    server.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        // do something
        return {message: 'OK'}; // or res.json({message: 'OK'});
    });
    server.listen(3000);

    return () => {
        server.stop();
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **componentWillMount()** with the code below:

```
componentWillMount() {
  // initalize the server (now accessible via localhost:1234)
  httpBridge.start(5561, "SERVICENAME", function(request) {

      // you can use request.url, request.type and request.postData here
      if (request.type === "GET" && request.url.split("/")[1] === "users") {
        httpBridge.respond(request.requestId, 200, "application/json", "{\"message\": \"OK\"}");
      } else {
        httpBridge.respond(request.requestId, 400, "application/json", "{\"message\": \"Bad Request\"}");
      }

  });
}
```

Test:

```
curl <device_ip_address>:5561/users -v
```

You should get:

```
{"message": "OK"}
```

Ref.: https://github.com/alwx/react-native-http-bridge/issues/15

Comment: Hey, the "bonjourName" is just a string, it can be anything. Like, I mentioned in my answer, the "SERVICENAME",  it's the same thing which you did. I am sure, that you might be doing something else, due to which your app was crashing.

Comment: @saberprashant I was missing the "SERVICENAME " and the request.requestId in the httpBridge.respond()

Comment: okay @Slipstream, I am happy that the string solution worked for you. Cheers buddy :)

Comment: @saberprashant if i send a post request from an html form hosted on that local server. how can i access that data example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post 
ifi i use this form how can i access fname and lname ? i tried request.postData i am getting undefined